# Delete items from a list that are not dictionary items-values in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Be the following list of elements:

```
list = ['aaa', 'xxx', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'xxx', 'bb']
```

also be the following dictionary

```
dict = {111:'aaa', 222:'bbb', 333:'ccc', 444:'ddd'}
```

I would like to delete the elements of the list that are NOT among the items (values) of the dictionary, that is, the new list will look like this:

```
list_new = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```

I did the following function in python:

```
for keys, value in enumerate(list):
    if value not in dict.values():
        list.remove(value)
```

The function should check if the dictionary values are in the list, if they are not, then delete. However, this function misses some elements (it does not delete all that you should delete). Any idea? What's wrong?

Comment: Do not delete items from a list you‘re looping over. Create a new one instead. Additionally, do not call your variables `list` or sth.

Comment: `[item for item in l if item in d.values()]` or `list(set(l) & set(d.values()))`. P.S. you shouldn't name variables `list` or `dict` those are built in names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jan pointed out, you shouldn't alter a list while iterating through it, since that can cause unwanted behaviour. You can, instead, create another list using list comprehension:

```py
my_list = ['aaa', 'xxx', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'xxx', 'bb']
my_dict = {111:'aaa', 222:'bbb', 333:'ccc', 444:'ddd'}
my_new_list = [value for value in my_list if value in my_dict.values()]
```

To clarify on why you shouldn't alter a list while looping through it: removing a value from a list alter the index of all the following elements. For example, if I have a list `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` and I remove the value `'c'`, the values `'d'` and `'e'` would have their indexes subtracted by 1, since the list would now be `['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']`. The problem is `for` iterates through a list by their indexes, what would cause value `'d'` to be skipped from the iteration. Code example:

```py
>>> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> for value in my_list:
...     print(value)
...     if value == 'c':
...         my_list.remove(value)
...
a
b
c
e
```

Comment: oh, I now understood why the code behaved in a "strange" way. It worked. Appreciate. =)